# SSIS job with import from onedrive does not work

Tags: sql-server, ssis, onedrive

I do have a flatfile-source where I import a Excel.csv stored on my PC which works perfect. I then thought it is more efficient for me to place the excel.csv in my OneDrive. Changed the flatfile-source to the OneDrive-Excel.csv and ran it on VisualStudio which worked perfect. But after providing the file in the SSISDB and ran it as a Job, I get an error saying it can't open the file on OneDrive. the failed link shows as "C:\Users\UserID\OneDrive..." and I have the Feeling that the link must be written a different way or do you have any other ideas how to solve the Problem? tx

Comment: My assumption is that the user that is running the job step does not have access to `C:\users\UserID\OneDrive` ... The quick test would be to create a Credential and Proxy and then set that as the user in your sql agent job `USE master;
GO
CREATE CREDENTIAL [ColumnA] WITH IDENTITY = N'domain\user', SECRET = N'pass1';
GO
USE msdb;
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_proxy
    @proxy_name = N'SSISProxy'
,   @credential_name = N'ColumnA'
,   @enabled = 1;
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_grant_proxy_to_subsystem
    @proxy_name = N'SSISProxy'
,   @subsystem_id = 11;
GO
`

Comment: thx for the Input, got it run, perfect

Comment: Was it a permission issue that you resolved via credential and proxy or was it a separate issue?

Comment: fixed it via credential and proxy, was not used to that and will read more into to understand it better